# want to popup the python window every time the batch file is executed

Tags: python, batch-file

Please see below code snippet.

```
count = 0
while ( count < freq ):
    os.chdir('Z:\\')
    os.system(path + " ")
    for iteration in range(delay):
        time.sleep(60)
    count += 1
```

here freq, delay and path are variable to which user will provide values.

Here I am trying to execute a bat file after every provided delay by user.
when I run this script, it takes input from user and execute bat file in python terminal.
next time after provided delay it again execute that bat file in the same python window as below.

But I this code to execute the bat file every time in new window which should popup every time the bat file is executed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for the subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
count = 0
while ( count < freq ):
    subprocess.Popen("Z:\\" + path)
    for iteration in range(delay):
        time.sleep(60)
    count += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this didn't solved my issue. That bat file runs in python terminal and second time it again runs in the same python terminal.
I want to run the bat file everytime in new python terminal.